# How to set up personal information alist with defcustom

Tags: customize, defcustom, alists

I would like to have a variable, say `my-info` that would have an alist attached to it. In normal programming it would look like this:

```
(setq my-info '((my-name . "Giuseppe Sextus-Packus") (my-email . "joep@packllc.com") (my-phone . "39.06.4434.0147")))
```

However, I want to populate `my-info` in a customization buffer, i.e., callable with `customize-variable my-info`. Furthermore, I would like each key to be presented with a blank field to fill in the value. I know I have to declare this variable as a `defcustom` but the details of offering all three keys for the user to complete with values is beyond my understanding. Are there templates out there for how to declare such a `defcustom`? How could I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```el
(defcustom foo-alist
  '((key-a "value-a1" "value-a2")
    (key-b "value-b1" "value-b2"))
  "Each element is a list comprising (KEY \"VALUE1\" \"VALUE2\") ..."
  :type '(alist :key-type (symbol :tag "Key")
                :value-type (list (string :tag "Value 1")
                                  (string :tag "Value 2")))
  :group 'foo)
```

Or in this particular case:

```el
(defcustom my-info-alist
  '((my-name . "Giuseppe Sextus-Packus")
    (my-email . "joep@packllc.com")
    (my-phone . "39.06.4434.0147"))
  "Each element is a cons cell (KEY . \"VALUE1\") ..."
  :type '(alist :key-type (symbol :tag "Key")
                :value-type (string :tag "Value"))
  :group 'my-info)
```

Comment: I guess the second example would create the alist `my-info-alist` already populated with values for the keys. But is there a way to create the customization group `my-info` where the values were left to be filled in by the individual user?

Comment: You can just use empty strings as the default values, no?

Comment: Of course. Excellent.

Comment: You can also use `nil` as the default value (if that's appropriate for use). Your tags plus Customize type-checking should be sufficient to guide a user to enter legitimate values. That's what they're for. You should be able to use the default value that is most appropriate *as the default value* for default, immediate use, and not have to come up with a default value whose purpose is to help someone understand the value structure and typing.